# Masked input at JSX

Tags: input, reactjs, jsx

At the beginning I want to say, that I'm beginner and don't know almost anything=)

So I have a JSX script, that take data from `input` fields.

```
render: function () {
    var disabledSubmitButton = this.state.SubmitButtonDisabled ? "disabled" : "";
    var disabledPortInput = this.state.IsPortInputDisabled ? "disabled" : "";
    return (
        <form className="form" method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <br />
    
            <div className="form-group">
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    name="Id"
                    type="hidden"
                    placeholder="Id"
                    ref="id"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </div>
    
            <div className="form-group">
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    name="UserName"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Имя пользователя"
                    ref="username"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </div>
    
            <div className="form-group">
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    name="PasswordHash"
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Пароль"
                    ref="passwordhash"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </div>
    
            <div className="form-group">
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    name="Email"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="E-mail"
                    ref="email"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </div>
    
            <div className="form-group">
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    name="UserRoles"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Роль пользователя"
                    ref="userroles"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </div>
    
            <input
                className="btn btn-default"
                value="Submit"
                type="submit"
                disabled={disabledSubmitButton}
            />
        </form>
    );

}
```

But I need a masked input for e-mail and password field, so how can I do that? (preferably only with the power of react)

Comment: Isn't the password field masked at the moment?

Comment: Maybe this help you: https://github.com/insin/react-maskedinput

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you mean by "masked input"? Do you mean masked = password: **** or masked = date: yy/mm/dd? Or something else?